# Returning a cursor from a function and using it in a variable

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have 2 function declared within a package.

In the first function I return a cursor.

In the second function I call the first function and store the returned cursor in a variable.

I am getting errors when I try to open the cursor to loop through it.

Here is my package spec:

```
create or replace PACKAGE CURSOR_EXAMPLE AS 

  FUNCTION get_cursor ( tId IN NUMBER ) RETURN SYS_REFCURSOR;

  FUNCTION use_cursor ( tId IN NUMBER ) RETURN VARCHAR2;

END CURSOR_EXAMPLE;
```

Here is my package body:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE 
PACKAGE BODY CURSOR_EXAMPLE AS

  FUNCTION get_cursor ( tId IN NUMBER ) RETURN SYS_REFCURSOR AS

    my_cursor SYS_REFCURSOR;

  BEGIN

    OPEN my_cursor FOR 

       SELECT * 
       FROM example_table eT 
       WHERE eT.PARENT_ID = tId;

      --CLOSE my_cursor;
      RETURN my_cursor;

  END get_cursor;

  FUNCTION use_cursor ( tId IN NUMBER ) RETURN VARCHAR2 AS

    my_cursor SYS_REFCURSOR;

  BEGIN

    my_cursor := get_cursor(tId);

    OPEN my_cursor;

        FOR my_rec in my_cursor

        LOOP

          DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('ID: ' || my_rec.table_id );   
          -- find_leaf_node(llf_rec.llf_id)

        END LOOP;

      CLOSE my_cursor;

      RETURN NULL;

  END use_cursor;

END CURSOR_EXAMPLE;
```

Here is the table that they access:

```
    table_id    parent_id
1   1           (null)  
2   2           1
3   3           2
4   4           3
5   5           4
6   6           1
7   7           6
8   8           1
9   9           8
10  10          1
11  11          10
```

When I remove the errors from use_cursor and run get-cursor

```
select CURSOR_EXAMPLE.get_cursor(3) from dual;
```

gives me

```
{<TABLE_ID=4,PARENT_ID=3>,}
```

Here are the errors that SQL Developer is giving me:

```
OPEN my_cursor; - Error(29,5): PLS-00382: expression is of wrong type

FOR my_rec in my_cursor - Error(31,23): PLS-00221: 'MY_CURSOR' is not a procedure or is undefined
```

I'm not that familiar with pl/sql so I'm not sure if this is a small syntax issue or that it's just not possible.

Any directions or help would be most welcome. 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

You cannot use `FOR..IN..LOOP` to fetch from a `SYS_REFCURSOR`.  You need to do it yourself.  Hopefully this will get you started -- it's a modified version of the code you posted.

```
DECLARE
  -- You need a variable to fetch into
  l_record DBA_OBJECTS%ROWTYPE;
  -- This holds the results of use_cursor() function
  dummy varchar2(1);

  FUNCTION get_cursor (tid IN NUMBER)
    RETURN SYS_REFCURSOR AS
    my_cursor   SYS_REFCURSOR;
  BEGIN
    OPEN my_cursor FOR
      SELECT *
      -- Changed to DBA_OBJECTS since I do not have your table
      FROM   dba_objects et
      WHERE  et.object_id < tid;

    --CLOSE my_cursor;
    RETURN my_cursor;
  END get_cursor;

  FUNCTION use_cursor (tid IN NUMBER)
    RETURN VARCHAR2 AS
    my_cursor   SYS_REFCURSOR;
  BEGIN
    my_cursor   := get_cursor (tid);

    LOOP
      FETCH my_cursor INTO l_record;
      EXIT WHEN my_cursor%NOTFOUND;
      DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('ID: ' || l_record.object_id);
    END LOOP;

    CLOSE my_cursor;

    RETURN NULL;
  END use_cursor;

BEGIN
  dummy := use_cursor (50);
END;
```